# Which XSLT profiler should I use?

Tags: profiling, xslt, xalan, xslt-tools

I'm in the market for an XSLT profiler.

1. I'm using the Xalan-j XSLT processor from Apache.
2. I'd like to be able to run the profiler under Windows or Linux as we have different teams using the same XML and XSLT on different platforms.
3. The tool needs to be able to work with exslt extensions.
4. The tool needs to be able to work with large (MB) input XML documents.
5. I'm not entirely adverse to paying for the right tool, but free (as in beer) would be nice.

I'm interested in hearing from people who have successfully used the tool that they recommend.

**EDIT:** updated, yes, xalan-j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're talking about Xalan/J; I'm not aware of the options for Xalan/C++.

[Stylus Studio](http://www.stylusstudio.com/xslt_profiler.html) had one in older versions, but it was dropped for Xalan in the current release.

The only other commercial one for Xalan that I am aware of that is any good is from [Oxygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/xslt_debugger.html#profiling).

Note that sometimes switching on the profiler switches the XSLT engine into a debugging mode so that certain optimizations are not performed, so the profiler results should be taken with some common sense.